# Properties of the evaluation functional of a space of polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

Let $K$ be a field. Let $E=K_{n}[x] = \{p(x) \in K[x] : degree(p(x)) \le n\}$.

(a) Given $a \in K$, show that the lineat transformation $\omega: E \rightarrow K $ defined by $\omega(p(x))=p(a)$ it's an element of $E^{*}$ (the dual space of $E$).

(b) Determine the dimension and a basis of $\ker \omega$.

My idea to solve (a) was to show that $\omega$ is linear, in the way that it verifies the next points:

$\omega(p(x)+q(x))=\omega(p(x)) +\omega(q(x))$,

$\omega(\lambda p(x))=\lambda(\omega(p(x)))$,

with $\lambda \in K$ and $p(x),q(x) \in E$.

Is that right?

To solve (b), I would appreciate any hint, because I don't know if I have to find $\ker \omega$ as if it was a linear transform, or the fact that it is a linear functional infuences the way to find it.

As always, thank you so much fot your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About (b): in general, we have that if $\;\dim V=k\;$  and $\;T:V\to W\;$ is a linear map, then the dimension theorem tells us

$$\dim\ker T+\dim\text{Im}\, T=k$$

In our case we have $\;\dim_K E=n\;,\;\;\dim_KK=1\;$ , and since the map $\;\omega\;$ is onto (as is **any** non zero linear functional), we then get

$$\dim\ker\omega+\dim\text{Im}\,\omega=n\implies \dim\ker \omega=n-\dim\text{Im}\,\omega=n-1$$

Thus, $\;\ker\omega\;$ is a hyperplane or maximal subspace of $\;E\;$ , and following more or less the hint in the other answer, it's easy to prove that

$$\left\{x-a\,,\,(x-a)^2\,,\,\ldots,\,(x-a)^n\right\}$$

are linearly independent and thus a basis of $\;\ker\omega\;$

Answer (score 0):

(a) Yes, linearity follows from the definition of the evaluation of a polynomial at a point.

(b) The kernel of $\omega$ consists of all the polynomials $P$ of degree smaller or equal to $n$ such that $a$ is a root of $P$. We can show that we can write them as $(X-a)Q(X)$, where $\deg Q\leqslant n-1$.

Comment: Thanks Davide. Then, I can say that the set of the polynoms of $\ker \omega$ is $\{p(a)=0 : a \in K\}$. How I can find the dimension of that subspace from this?

Comment: Do you know what the dimension of the kernel of a linear functional over a finite dimensional space is?

Comment: I know that the dimension of a linear transformation over a finite vector space is, but I don't know if I can apply this to linear functionals of a dual space. I thought that I could do: A basis of $\omega$ is $(1,a,a^{2},...,a^{n})$, and then, from this, find the kernel as I've done always with linear transformations, but I'm almost sure that this way to do this is wrong.

Comment: What you say is a basis of $\;\omega\;$ cannot possibly be a basis of anything since it is only a set with $\;n+1\;$ *scalars* or polynomials of degree zero, which of course cannot be linearly independent.